# How to hide Macros or password protect in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: macros, passwords, powerpoint

Hello all I made a PowerPoint that is heavily on the macros the problem is I don't want the users to see the macro's. Is there a way to protect my code or am I just SOL?

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VBA IDE:

Tools | Project Properties | Protection tab

Checkmark next to "Lock project for viewing"
Type a password, confirm it, click OK then save the presentation.

It's not totally secure by any means, but it'll keep most users out of your code.